# Why does having a `packages` property in pyproject.toml affect mypy's behaviour?

Tags: python, mypy, python-poetry, pyproject.toml

I've been having the issue that Mypy suddenly no longer type checks the contents of my imports, even though they are in the same source tree. After bisecting the issue, I figured out that the cause was the addition of the `packages` line to my pyproject.toml file by a co-worker. He claims it must be there for use with another program which uses the aforementioned source as a git submodule, which would makes sense given that I presume he's adding it as [a `path` dependency with `develop` set](https://python-poetry.org/docs/dependency-specification/#path-dependencies) (we use Poetry for dependency management). With that established, simply removing the `packages` line is clearly not an option. As such, I made a minimal reproducer to study the problem better:

pyproject.toml:

```ini
[tool.poetry]
name = "mypy-issue-reproducer"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = ["Your Name <you@example.com>"]
readme = "readme.md"
packages = [
    { include = "**/*.py" },
]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.10"

[tool.poetry.group.dev.dependencies]
mypy = "^1.8.0"

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

reproducer-main.py:

```py
from some_module.other_module.reproducer_import import main

main()
```

some_module/other_module/reproducer-import.py:

```py
def main() -> None:
    # blatant violation
    variable: str = 1
```

readme.md also needs to be created and can contain whatever.

Creating these files and installing the project with `$ poetry install --with dev`, then running `$ poetry run mypy reproducer-main.py` reproduces the issue (note how mypy does not complain about the blatant type violation in reproducer-import.py). Removing the `packages` property, then removing the virtualenv and repeating the install and Mypy steps now has Mypy actually report the aforementioned type violation. But why? And what can I do to make Mypy type check this import while keeping the package installable as [a `path` dependency with `develop` set](https://python-poetry.org/docs/dependency-specification/#path-dependencies)?